# How to copy rectangular regions without visual in Vim

Tags: vim, editor

I'm currently editing massive amounts of tabulated data in Vim and would like to smoothen my workflow by entering the visual mode only when strictly necessary. I know that one way to select rows and columns in a tabulated notebook is to engage the visual block mode with the combination `<C-v>`. But this requires me to perform the operation one block at a time. I would prefer to mark the upper left corners of the columns by `ma`, `mc`, `me`, etc., and the lower right corners by `mb`, `md`, `mf`, etc., and then copy the regions to registers with something like 'a "a y 'b, 'c "a y 'd, etc. (with ticks replaced by backticks). However, the standard copy treats the text along the normal movements that traverse line breaks rather than the rectangular movements suited for table blocks. Is there a way to restrict the copy to a rectangular block?

Answer (score 0):

While you could avoid blockwise visual mode altogether (by grabbing the range of lines via [`:help getline()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getline%28%29) and then filtering the desired columns via [`matchstr()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#matchstr%28%29) and the [`:help /\%v`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25v) atom), I think you're better off to keep using visual mode.

What you can do to automate the text retrival is either a *macro*, or a Vimscript *function*. In both, you'd use the same normal and visual mode commands as during interactive use (that's a really nice property of Vim: there's an almost seamless progression from one-off macros to reusable macros to custom functions).

```
:execute "normal! g`a\<C-v>g`b\"ay"
```

This stores the block delimited by marks `a` and `b` into register `a`. Turning that into a function (that takes the marks and register as arguments):

```
function! CopyRectangle(upperLeftMark, lowerRightMark, targetRegister)
    execute printf("normal! g`%s\<C-v>g`%s\"%sy",
    \   a:upperLeftMark, a:lowerRightMark, a:targetRegister)
endfunction
call CopyRectangle('a', 'b', 'a')
```

I hope you can take it from here...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reselect the same visual area as last time, you can simply use a count for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> command.

E.g. you selected the last time a 3x3 area using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> and copied it. Now you move you cursor 10 lines below to a different area. If you now press, e.g. <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> Vim will create a new blockwise region starting from your cursor position downwards with the same size as last time (If you need a region that is twice as big, use the <kbd>2</kbd> count (e.g. the count acts as multiplier).